# Understanding a Step from a Proof involving Haar Functions

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

In $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, let

$$
I_{j,k} = [k2^{-j}, (k+1)2^{-j}) \subset \mathbb{R} \text{ for $k$,$j \in \mathbb{Z}$ }
$$

and the Haar function $h_I(x)$ be defined as

$$
h_I(x) := (1/\sqrt{|I|}) (\chi_{I_r}(x) - \chi_{I_{l}}(x))
$$

where $I$ is shorthand for an interval of form $I_{j,k}$ and if $I = [a, b)$ then the notation $I_l$ and $I_r$ denotes

$$
I_l = [a, (a+b)/2)
$$

$$
I_r = [(a+b)/2, b)
$$

From a step from a proof in a textbook:

> [image]

**Question:** Why is there a factor of $\frac{\sqrt{|I|}}{2}$ in this equality? It seems to me that

$$
⟨f, h_I⟩h_{I}(x) = ∫ fh_{I} h_I (x) = \left( {1 \over |I_r|} \int_{I_r} f - {1 \over |I_l|} \int_{I_l} f  \right) h_{I}(x)
$$

So where does this extra factor come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner product of $f$ with $h_I$ is not as you've written. It is
$$
⟨f, h_I⟩ = ∫ fh_{I}  =  \int f\frac1{\sqrt{|I|}}(\chi_{I_r}-\chi_{I_l})=
\frac1{\sqrt{|I|}}\int_{I_r} f - \frac1{\sqrt{|I|}} \int_{I_l} f .
$$
Remember that $|I|=2|I_l|=2|I_r|$, so you can write the first coefficient  $1/\sqrt{|I|}$ as
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{|I|}}=\frac{\sqrt{|I|}}{|I|}=\frac{\sqrt{|I|}}{2|I_r|}$$
and the second one as
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{|I|}}=\frac{\sqrt{|I|}}{|I|}=\frac{\sqrt{|I|}}{2|I_l|}$$